# Get Xpath of an iframe element that has a 'src' attribute containing a certain substring using contains()

Tags: html, xpath

In HTML document I have `iframe`, which has a `src` attribute, containing a certain substring "yahoo.com":

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://search.yahoo.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What would be the correct Xpath expression for that `iframe`?

How do I use the `contains()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I use `contains()` function?

If you want to select an `iframe` that contains the string "yahoo.com" in the `src` attribute, use:

```
//iframe[contains(@src,'yahoo.com')]
```